# Is it possible to add/remove props of components from a method on the main Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, click, dom-events

On Vue.js, I have a v-button component with a `prop` named *loading*.

**Component:**

```
Vue.component('v-button', {
    props: ['loading'],
    template: '<button class="btn btn-info"> <span v-if="loading != undefined">Loading...</span> <span v-else><slot></slot></span> </button>'
});
```

**Vue:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: ['v-button'],
    methods: {
        niceMethod: function(argument) {
        console.log(argument);
        // Considering that I will have a large amount of v-buttons:
        // Is it possible to do something here to add or remove the prop "loading" ONLY on the v-button I've clicked?
    }
  }
})
```

**Body:**

```
<div id="app" class="p-5">
  <p><v-button @click.native="niceMethod('testing!')">Test</v-button></p>
  <p><v-button @click.native="niceMethod('hello!')">Hello</v-button></p>
  <p><v-button @click.native="niceMethod('vue!')">Vuejs</v-button></p>
</div>
```

Considering that I will have a large amount of v-buttons: Is it possible to do something on the Vue instance to **add** or **remove** the prop *loading* only on the v-button I've clicked?

Did I missed something on Vue.js docs?

Sorry if my question is not clear... If so, please check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericgruby/cgas7vm1/) I did.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just toggle a data `loading` true/false inside the component ?

```js
Vue.component('v-button', {
  template: '<button class="btn btn-info" @click="clickMe"> <span v-if="loading">Loading...</span> <span v-else><slot></slot></span> </button>',
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickMe() {
      this.loading = !this.loading
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: ['v-button'],
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p><v-button>Test</v-button></p>
  <p><v-button>Hello</v-button></p>
  <p><v-button>Vuejs</v-button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know it can be done like this :) At this moment I'm using 2 different components:

- 1 is the _v-button_
- 2 is a component that uses _v-button_ on his template + "loading" method in it, just the way you answered.

However, I was wondering if I could use _v-button_ as a generic button across my app, leaving all methods for the main Vue instance to handle. Sounds crazy, and it's kinda against the whole vue component idea, but I'm just wondering.